# Control Egress Traffic Configuration To Access Outside URL

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to access the following db in my flask app

```
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'pymongo_db'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds163984.mlab.com:63984/pymongo_db'
```

but istio is blocking me so I created a `ServiceEntry` and a `VirtualService`. However, I think my config is wrong as it's not working correctly. Can somehow tell me what I'm doing wrong? https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mlab
spec:
  hosts:
  - wwww.ds163984.mlab.com
  - ds163984.mlab.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mlab
spec:
  hosts:
  - wwww.ds163984.mlab.com
  - ds163984.mlab.com
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - wwww.ds163984.mlab.com
      - ds163984.mlab.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ds163984.mlab.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off hand, I see at least a couple of things wrong with your configuration. The port in your `ServiceEntry` and `VirtualService` should be the mongodb port (63984), not 443, and the protocol should be TLS, not HTTPS.

There is an [excellent blog post](https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-mongo/) on various ways to configure access to mongodb. It sounds like [this section](https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-mongo/#control-tls-egress-traffic-without-a-gateway) is what you are trying to do.